# How do ngXs lambda selects know which state to look in?

Tags: angular, ngxs

According to the NGXS documentation, the following is all valid code:

```js
import { Select } from '@ngxs/store';
import { ZooState, ZooStateModel } from './zoo.state';

@Component({ ... })
export class ZooComponent {
  // Reads the name of the state from the state class
  @Select(ZooState) animals$: Observable<string[]>;

  // Uses the pandas memoized selector to only return pandas
  @Select(ZooState.pandas) pandas$: Observable<string[]>;

  // Also accepts a function like our select method
  @Select(state => state.zoo.animals) animals$: Observable<string[]>;

  // Reads the name of the state from the parameter
  @Select() zoo$: Observable<ZooStateModel>;
}
```

My question is specifically about that third `@Select`. How, exactly, does the decorator and/or framework know *which* state should be used in the lambda? There is nothing obvious here to say "this component uses ZooState as its state object," so how can the correct state slice to look at be determined?

For the record, this pattern does seem to work just fine - I'm just a bit stumped as to HOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the NGXS `@Select` decorator with a function referring to the target state, the `state` arg in this case represents the whole state object that contains all the registerd states by their names that provided within `@State` decorator (such as: `@State<ZooStateModel>({ name: 'zoo' })`)

For example, if you have 3 states, defined as: `zoo`, `app`, and `foo`, and registed within the store, then the type of the `state` arg will be like the following:

```js
@Select((state: { zoo: ZooStateModel; app: AppStateModel; foo: FooStateModel }) => state.zoo.animals)
animals$: Observable<string[]>;
```

Comment: Ah, duh, of course. I was a bit thrown off by my own experience - I didn't actually have to specify the full state path with state name, but this particular component also only has access to a single state object, so I'm guessing it's not necessary if there's only one State object available in your module.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to say or ask exactly!? :)

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear... What I was saying is that I have a component that's just doing `@Select(state => state.property)` rather than `@Select(state => state.stateSlice.property)`. I'm guessing that the reason that works is that the component that contains the `@Select` only has access to that one state object via the `NgxsModule.forFeature(MyState)` in the .module.ts file.